# Over-optimization bug in 10.9 Core Data Entity Description methods?

Tags: core-data, osx-mavericks

When I send -objectForKey: to the dictionary returned by -[NSManagedObjectModel entitiesByName], -objectForKey: returns the expected result if the passed-in key is a literal constant such as @“foo”.  But if I instead pass in a local variable whose value is constructed to be equal to @“foo”, -objectForKey: returns nil in Mac OS X 10.9.  In Mac OS X 10.8, it returns the expected value, whether the key is a constant or not.

The problem is probably due to the fact that, in 10.9, -entitiesByName returns a subclass of NSDictionary called NSKnownKeysDictionary2.  In 10.8, it returns NSKnownKeysDictionary1.  My guess is that

- During optimization, the compiler coalesces any duplicate constant strings into one.
- NSKnownKeysDictionary2 is optimized based on the assumption that keys are such constants, and thus uses pointer equality instead of -isEquals:.

According to the documentation, [-[NSManagedObjectModel entitiesByName] returns an NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectModel/entitiesByName), which is in turn [documented to use -isEquals: to compare keys](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDictionary) …

*Within a dictionary, the keys are unique. That is, no two keys in a single dictionary are equal (as determined by isEqual:).*

So I think this is a bug in Mac OS X 10.9.  I think that maybe someone didn't notice that -[NSManagedObjectModel entitiesByName] was a public method when they optimized it to return NSKnownKeysDictionary2.  Since most developers use constant strings for entity names, this bug slipped all the way through the Developer Previews and no one noticed.

Am I wrong, or should I "file a bug"?

Thanks,

Jerry Krinock

---

Code demonstrating this (from my project, sorry) is below.  It is from my personal “super subclass” of NSManagedObject, which does all of my favorite things that NSManagedObject does not.

As you can see from my “First try” in the code, the results of method +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:] are also affected by this apparent bug.

When I run build the app and run in Mac OS X 10.8, it logs

- 1st try worked for Stark_entity
- 1st try worked for Ixporter_entity

But when I run the same build in 10.9, with the same data, the 1st, 2nd and 3rd tries apparently fail, because it instead logs

- 4th try worked for Stark_entity
- 4th try worked for Ixporter_entity

Code:

```
// How I like to name my entities…
+ (NSString*)entityNameForClass:(Class)class {
    return [NSStringFromClass(class) stringByAppendingString:@"_entity"] ;
}

+ (NSEntityDescription*)entityDescription {
    // Stuff we'll need
    NSArray* bundles = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSBundle mainBundle]] ;
    NSManagedObjectModel* mom = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:bundles] ;
    NSString* entityName = [self entityNameForClass:self] ; // See above

    // What we want
    NSEntityDescription* entityDescription = nil ;

    // First try.
    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator* psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:mom] ;
    NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init] ;
    [moc setPersistentStoreCoordinator:psc] ;
    entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName
                                                         inManagedObjectContext:moc] ;
    [psc release] ;
    [moc release] ;

    NSDictionary* entities = [mom entitiesByName] ;
    NSLog(@"entities is an %@", [entities className]) ;
    NSLog(@"entityName is an %@", [entityName class]) ;
    NSLog(@"entities is a dictionary? = %hhd”,
         [entities isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) ;

    if (entityDescription) {
        NSLog(@"1st try worked for %@", entityName) ;
    }
    else {
        // Second try

        entityDescription = [entities objectForKey:entityName] ;
        if (!entityDescription) {
            // Third try
            NSString* entityNameCopy = [entityName copy] ;
            entityDescription = [entities objectForKey:entityNameCopy] ;
            [entityNameCopy release] ;
        }
        if (!entityDescription) {
            // Fourth try
            NSSet* candidateEntityNames = [NSSet setWithObjects:
                                           @"Stark_entity",
                                           @"Ixporter_entity",
                                           nil] ;
            for (NSString* candidate in candidateEntityNames) {
                if ([entityName isEqualToString:candidate]) {
                    entityDescription = [entities objectForKey:candidate] ;
                    if (entityDescription) {
                        NSLog(@"4th try worked for %@", entityName) ;
                        break ;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!entityDescription) {
        NSLog(@"Internal Error 561-3831 for %@", entityName) ;
    }

    return entityDescription ;
}
```

Comment: There is an easy workaround for this apparent bug. First of all, do not use +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]. Instead, use -[NSManagedObjectModel entitiesByName], and wrap it with +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:].

Comment: I believe I am now seeing the same behavior with iOS 7.1 and `-[NSEntityDescription propertiesByName]`. I think this qualifies as a bug. Did you ever file one?

Comment: It appears that I did not.  You're the first one to care :)

Comment: I'm just getting around to filing a Radar for this, but now I can't reproduce it. Can you easily check if you still see this behavior in Mavericks?

Comment: Well, it wasn't easy, but yes I'm still getting it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it now in my real project or in simplified sample code. Frustrating, as I filed a Radar (16755816), but I know Apple will ask for a sample project demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I'm still able to reproduce it if I roll back to my old code in my real project; -entitiesByName returns a NSKnownKeysDictionary2 and the bug bites.  But when I try to reproduce it in a demo project, -entitiesByName returns a NSKnownKeysDictionary1 and the bug doesn't bite.  Maybe I can beat on it some more later.

Comment: I'm seeing this bug running on the "iPad Air (7.1)" simulator & on an iPad mini in Xcode 6.1.

Comment: I ran into this bug while enabling 64-bit support on a project. No problems before adding arm64. The method that failed me was attributesByName and the return type was NSKnownKeysDictionary2. OS X 10.9 and iOS 7 simulator.